# Looking for advice on effectively using REDIS Cache in a large application

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures, redis, hashtable

We have a use case where we have to store some user IDs(`testUserId`) in REDIS and mark them as test users temporarily and also mark a testingMode Flag as active/inactive. We would have to then in an API check if the `testingMode` is active and then passed user ID is a test user or not.

So far what I have done is store a flag and an array containing list of users.

The issue with this implementation is that while checking we have to fetch the whole data from REDIS and convert that into List(array) and see if the `testUserId` is present or not. Some people have raised concerns over this being ineffective.

Is there any better way to do this?

I thought of storing `testUserId` as a key and `testingMode` flag as a value but then it will create too many rows. Will this be the best way or are there any better ways for this?

Comment: Simple is better and don't worry about having many keys in Redis. For Redis, your limit is your memory and that's valid for everything (values), no just keys. In your use case i would simply store keys (with a whatever value) in the format `testuser:666` (with `666` in this example key being your internal user identifier). The business logic to determine if a certain user is a test user would be the mere existence of the key. Additionally, there's no concept of "rows" in Redis. Access to a particular record (via the key) is done in linear time, no matter how many records you have.

Comment: @nitrin0 I believe that you mean that access is done in constant time, not linear.  See https://redis.io/topics/data-types to verify.

Comment: @btilly exactly, should have used 0-notation :)

Comment: Went with @btilly suggested and used sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing a set of test users, and use https://redis.io/commands/exists to see if your current user is a test user.

This only has to lookup the test user.  And since very few of your users are expected to be test users, this stores very little data.

Please note that you should pay close attention to space usage with Redis.  It runs wonderfully...until your data gets too big for RAM and then it performs terribly.  So try to keep it from getting too big unnecessarily!

Comment: Thanks for this. I did it using sets and stored userIds separately and flag separately. I also added a second layer cache to hold the flag.